# Parsing a json response from swift

Tags: javascript, json, swift

I have the following code finally manage to get a response via json form the api.

```
 let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let bodyData = "title=foo&body=bar&userId=1"

        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
            (response, data, error) in
            let res = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(res)
        }
```

I am trying to learn swift as i thought it would be a bit like javascript i am getting a response like this.

```
Optional({
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 101
})
```

normally with javascript i would get a value by simply running response.body or something along those lines but cannot figure out how to parse a json response with swift.

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: Well, for starters, that's not a JSON response as long as the `Optional(` and `)` are there.

Comment: just to note i am learning Swift so be nice

Comment: I'm always nice, and I don't know anything about Swift. But that's still not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the JSON response into a Swift object like so:

```
let res = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Then you can access the values within like:

```
let title = res["title"]
```